# Perl Hash of Hash

Tags: perl, hash-of-hashes

So I am trying to use a Perl HoH and push some values into an array from the HoH.

Here is a portion of the code to better explain;

```
my $hoh = (
antenna_included=>{
    "1" => '1 MultiBand Antenna',
    "2" =>'2 Multiband Antennas',
    "3" =>'1 MultiBand Antenna & 2 WiFi Antennas',
    "4" =>'2 Multiband Cellular Antennas & 2 WiFi Antennas',
    "N" =>'No Antennas Included',
    },
ip_rating=>{
    I6 => 'IP 64',
    CD => 'Intrinsically Safe, Class 1 Div 2, IP 64',
    NI => 'No',
    });

foreach $group ( sort keys %hoh ) {
    foreach $spec ( sort keys %{ $hoh{$group} } ) {   
        print "$spec=>$hoh{$group}{$spec}\n";
    }

    print "what part is it: ";
    my $input = <STDIN>;
    chomp $input;

    if ( exists $hoh{$group} ) {
        print "$hoh{$spec}\n";                #this is the problematic line.  
    }
    else {
    print "not a match!\n";
    }
}
```

Basically the goal of this script is to loop through the HoH, but throughout each block of hash it gives `STDIN`, then you type in the `key`, and then then I want to push the `value` of that element into an array. (Right now the code just says `print` for debugging).

I have tried

```
$hoh{$group}{$spec}
$hoh{$group}
$hoh{$group}->{$spec}
```

For `$hoh{$group}` I get `HASH(0x6ff920)` and all of the other values it is just blank, no error.

Any thoughts? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `->` operator.

Everything underneath the HoH is a hash**ref**, and accessing elements of those requires the `->` operator. (Technically, you have a "hash of hashref" not a "hash of hash," since such a thing isn't possible.)

See the [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) docs for details about references.

```
$hoh{$group}->{$spec}
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a modified version of your program. The differences are:

- The initial declaration of `%hoh` is done with the hash variable `%hoh`, not the scalar variable, `$hoh`. Assigning the initializing list to `$hoh` would result in the last element of the list being assigned to the variable, in this case, the hashref corresponding to `ip_rating`. This is almost certainly not what you want.
- Attempting to access an element of `$hoh{$group}` requires the `->` operator, like `$hoh{$group}->{$spec}.
- The problem area probably needs to be checking for the existence of `$hoh{$group}->{$input}`. If it doesn't exist, the input isn't valid, which is what the message suggests.

You just need to understand the difference between a hash and a hashref (similar to the difference between an array and an arrayref) and realize that hashes and arrays cannot be elements of other hashes or arrays. Hash**ref**s and array**ref**s can be elements of other data structures, because only scalars can be contained within another data structure. Hashes and arrays are not scalars, but *references* are scalars (including hashref, arrayrefs, coderefs, and even scalarrefs) and are necessary to create any sort of complex, nested data structure.

---

```
my %hoh = (
    antenna_included=>{
        "1" => '1 MultiBand Antenna',
        "2" =>'2 Multiband Antennas',
        "3" =>'1 MultiBand Antenna & 2 WiFi Antennas',
        "4" =>'2 Multiband Cellular Antennas & 2 WiFi Antennas',
        "N" =>'No Antennas Included',
    },
    ip_rating=>{
        I6 => 'IP 64',
        CD => 'Intrinsically Safe, Class 1 Div 2, IP 64',
        NI => 'No',
    });

foreach $group ( sort keys %hoh ) {
    foreach $spec ( sort keys %{ $hoh{$group} } ) {   
        print "$spec=>$hoh{$group}->{$spec}\n";
    }

    print "what part is it: ";
    my $input = <STDIN>;
    chomp $input;

    if ( exists $hoh{$group}->{$input} ) {
        print $hoh{$group}->{$input}."\n";
    }
    else {
        print "not a match!\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and the reference. That did'nt work (at least just adding that to the one "problematic" line).  Do you think it may be because I need to use the `->`operator on the `for` loops above and then I will be able to reference it?

Answer (score 1):

Braces `{...}` and parentheses `(...)` are very diffferent. The first defines an anonymous hash, which you would assign to a *scalar* variable, while the second defines a list, which you would assign to a *hash* variable. You have a mixture of the two, and it isn't clear which you meant.

- If you have a *scalar* variable `$hoh` then you need to initialise it with

  ```
  my $hoh = { ... }
  ```

  and access the elements with the indirection operator

  ```
  $hoh->{$group}->{$spec}
  ```

  or

  ```
  $hoh->{$group}{$spec}
  ```
- If you have a *hash* variable then you need to initialise it with

  ```
  my %hoh = ( ... )
  ```

  and access the elements directly

  ```
  $hoh{$group}->{$spec}
  ```

  or

  ```
  $hoh{$group}{$spec}
  ```

Comment: @mojo: `perl -E'%hoh = (G => {S => works}); ($group, $spec) = qw/G S/; say $hoh{$group}{$spec}'`

Comment: I stand corrected. I don't understand why, if `$hoh={...}`, you cannot `$hoh{$key}`, but if `$hoh{$key}` returns a hashref, you can `$hoh{$key}{$subkey}` *AND* `$hoh{$key}->{$subkey}` with the same result.

Comment: @mojo: Because the indirection arrow is option *only between pairs of closing/opening braces `}{` or brackets `][`*. In any case, there would otherwise be no way of distinguishing between `$hoh{$key}` being an element of `%hoh` and `$hoh->{$key}` being an element of `%$hoh`.